# WebException No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto

Tags: c#, webservice, embebido, windows-mobile

Ejecuto mi programa desde el dispositivo real y cuando lo ejecuto sale ese error, investigando dice que es por falta de internet, verifico y el dispositivo efectivamente tiene internet, estoy desarrollando para Windows Embedded (Windows .Net o Windows Mobile o Windows CE) y el código del correo lo tengo en un sitio web el cual hago el llamado desde mi plantilla Smart Device, no sé si de pronto sería mas tema que el proyecto no acepte la conexion con sitio web.

```
ERROR: Prueba.exe
WebException
No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto
en System.net.HttpWebRequest.finishGetResponse()
en System.net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
en System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequestrequest)
en System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequestrequest)
en System.web.sercices.Protocols.SoapHttpWebClientProtocol.doInvokes(string methodName,Object[] parameters,WebClientAsyncResult AsyncResult) en Prueba.localhost.service.correo()
```

pues el codigo del correo en el sitio web es este

```
MailMessage objeto_mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 25;
    client.Host = "smtp.live.com";
    client.Timeout = 100000000;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("barton6661@hotmail.com", "password");
    objeto_mail.From = new MailAddress("barton6661@hotmail.com");
    objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("sistemas@autosnack.com.co"));
    objeto_mail.Subject = "Pedidos";

    List<string> Archivo = new List<string>();
    Archivo.Add("");
    Archivo.Add("");

    objeto_mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
    objeto_mail.Body = "se hizo el pedido y la orden esta adjuntada en el correo con un excell";
    client.EnableSsl = true;


    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))    
    {

        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;     

        objeto_mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "Pedido.cvs", "text/csv"));

        client.Send(objeto_mail);
    }
```

y en la plantilla del Smart Device lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
localhost.Service obj = new Prueba.localhost.Service();

        obj.Correo();
```

Comment: puedes desde el dispositivo desde el browser verificar la url del Webservice, si la estas probando por wifi con una ruta publica, verifica que tu wifi tenga acceso a esa ruta, ya que en algunas redes internas se impide el acceso a la ip publica.

Comment: pues la conexion es por un VPN publica de la empresa que nos presta el servicio de datos, no se si tenga algo de importancia ese tema

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que puedas conectar a smp.live.com a traves del puerto 25.

Prueba con:

```
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-windows-live-hotmail-smtp-settings-1170861