# Como exportar una base de datos a Excel y correo

Tags: c#, sql, embebido

Como seria el codigo para exportar los datos que estan insertados en una base de datos .sdf a un archivo excel. en C# y para visual studio 2008 y SQL Compact 3.5, y mi otra pregunta seria si yo necesito llamar un metodo  dentro del

> writer.WriteLine();

Como se haria el llamdo ya que si coloco el metodo dentro de los parentesis pues este me arroja el siguiente error

> la mejor coincidencia de metodo sobrecargado para "System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(string.Params object[])" tiene algunos argumentos no validos.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas ado.net para acceder al `sdf` entonces puedes generar un `datatable`, si es asi recomiendo evalues

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

con este podrias generar un excel directo asignando el datatable

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
DataTable dataTable = GetTable(); //aqui obtienes los datos del sdf

wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);

wb.SaveAs("Nombreexcel.xlsx");
```

asi de simple, con muy poco codigo, y lo mejor es que no necesitas tener office instalado en la pc para generar el excel

Comment: 'DataTable dataTable = GetTable(); //aqui obtienes los datos del sdf'
ahi donde dice **GetTable()**  me sale error me dice que no esta en el contexto actual

Comment: hey Leandro, el proyecto del buen @Cristian se está implementando en dispositivos con Windows CE 6.

Comment: @fredyfx si lo se, pero desde el device no se podra generar un documento, tendra que crear un servicio web y generar este en el servidor para luego enviarlo al device, o sino que se persista en el servidor

Comment: @LeandroTuttini entendido mi estimado :D gracias por el entrenamiento :D

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  pues yo tengo el servicio donde y hago el llamado en el proyecto del Windows Ce pero entonces me arroja el error de esta pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22282/webexception-no-es-posible-conectar-con-el-servidor-remoto

Answer (score 0):

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
using(var conn = new SqlCeConnection("STRINGCONECTION"))
{
    conn.Open();

    var comm = new SqlCeCommand("CONSULTA SQL", conn);
    SqlCeDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    wb.Worksheets.Add(reader);
    wb.SaveAs("Excel.xlsx");
}
```

Fijate si te sirve eso para guardar todos los datos de la consulta

Te dejo un link con ayuda por las dudas que esto no te sirva
http://moztrodev.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/hazlo-facil-exportar-datos-excel-con.html

Comment: 'wb.Worksheets.Add(reader);' aqui me sale el error
**no tiene algunos argumentos validos**
de resto todo funciona bien

Comment: @CristianR.M La información del link tampoco te sirvió?

Comment: no señor, me sale error ahi donde le comente y pues en el link lo manejan con datagridview por lo que pude ver y pues yo no ando utilizando eso por la razon que el proyecto por ser tan viejo no tiene la opcion.